# Postman request to Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, postman, swifty-json

I'm having no issues when I make the post request with POSTMAN but when I use alamofire I have issues. The post still goes through on the alamofire request but the data is not received the same way. What does an alamofire request look like that's the exact same as the following postman...

[image]

Comment: can you post some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 2.x**:

```
typealias apiSuccess = (result: NSDictionary?) -> Void
typealias apiProgress = (result: NSDictionary?) -> Void // when you want to download or upload using Alamofire..
typealias apiFailure = (error: NSDictionary?) -> Void

// Normal http request with JSON response..
func callJSONrequest(url:String, params:[String: AnyObject]?, success successBlock :apiSuccess,
                     failure failureBlock :apiFailure) {

    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print("\(response.request?.URL)")  // original URL request
            //print(response.response) // URL response
            //print(response.data)     // server data
            //print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let jsonDic = response.result.value as! NSDictionary
                successBlock(result: jsonDic)

            } else {
                let httpError: NSError = response.result.error!
                let statusCode = httpError.code
                let error:NSDictionary = ["error" : httpError,"statusCode" : statusCode]
                failureBlock(error: error)
            }
    }
}

func myFunction() {
    let myApiSuccess: apiSuccess = {(result: NSDictionary?) -> Void in
        print ("Api Success : result is:\n \(result)")
        // Here you can make whatever you want with result dictionary
    }

    let myApiFailure: apiFailure = {(error: NSDictionary?) -> Void in
        print ("Api Failure : error is:\n \(error)")
        // Here you can check the errors with error dictionary looking for http error type or http status code
    }
    var params :[String: AnyObject]?
    let email : String! = "stuart@gmail.com"
    let password : String! = "thisismypassword"
    params = ["email" : email, "password" : password]
    let url : String! = "https://arcane-brook-75067.herokuapp.com/login"
    callJSONrequest(url, params: params, success: myApiSuccess, failure: myApiFailure)
}
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to make this work. I get errors with the bottom function. First why is there a comma after the first bracket of the function... also I get 'expression resolves to unused function at each of the let myApiSuccess and let myApiFailure

Comment: I check now, probably some mistakes during copy and paste from my personal repo..wait..

Comment: thanks you, I had to add or remove some brackets and whatnot so I'm not sure what's wrong with it

Comment: I add to change the way my node server was sending the response (it wasn't a json) and now it all works! thank you very much man

Comment: What was the problem that the OP was having..?