# How to inherit a function with closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have define this function in my APIServices class

```
typealias APIResponseOK = (data:NSDictionary, extra:NSDictionary) -> Void
typealias APIResponseError = (failure:Bool, code:NSString, message:NSString) -> Void

func getHttp(action:NSString, onResult:APIResponseOK, onError:APIResponseError) -> Void {

    let strUrlRequst = String(format: "\(action)")

    Alamofire.request(.GET, strUrlRequst).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in

        if(responseData.result.error == nil){

            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                print("Response \(swiftyJsonVar)")

                onResult(data: swiftyJsonVar.dictionaryObject!, extra: swiftyJsonVar.dictionaryObject!);
            }
        }
        else{
            onError(failure: true, code: "OM_ERR", message: (responseData.result.error?.localizedDescription)!);
        }

    }
}
```

Now I want to inherit this function in ViewController class. What I tried is as bellow.

```
   apiServices.getHttp("Somename", onResult: (data:NSDictionary, extra:NSDictionary){

        },
    onError:(failure: Bool, code:NSString, message:NSString){


    })
```

Why i get this error. Please correct me, I am very much new to swift

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at how to write closures in Swift? That syntax you use is quite far off.

Comment: How have you declared APIResponseOK closure ????

Comment: Please see how i declare APIResponseOK. I have update the source code with the declarations

Comment: Take a look at http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/ for closure syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your function declaration :

```
func getHttp(action:NSString, onResult:APIResponseOK, onError:APIResponseError) -> Void {
```

with:

```
func getHttp(action:NSString, onResult:APIResponseOK, onError:APIResponseError) {
```

After that , to call this function you can do:

```
let myApiSuccess: APIResponseOK = {(data:NSDictionary?, extra:NSDictionary?) -> Void in
    print ("Api Success : result is:\n \(data)")
    // Here you can make whatever you want with your dictionaries
}

let myApiFailure: APIResponseError = {(failure:Bool?, code:NSString?, message:NSString?) -> Void in
    print ("Api Failure : error is:\n \(message)")
    // Here you can check the errors with your vars looking for failure, code and message
}

getHttp(action:NSString, onResult:APIResponseOK, onError:APIResponseError)
```

You can find more details in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37292960/1894067)

Answer (score 1):

```
apiServices.getHttp("Somename", onResult:{ data: NSDictionary, extra: NSDictionary in
    // some
}, onError:{ failure: Bool, code: NSString, message: NSString in
    // some
})
```

You should check all the Apple Swift documentation, instead of use it first. 
And other problems like, why you want use NSString or NSDictionary in Swift.