# Postman Body Raw Request To Swift Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to re-create this Postman settings for posting in Alamofire. This is my first time to see an API that requires both Parameters and a body with Raw Json.

I'm done with gathering and formatting my data (either in Json using SwiftyJSON or Dictionary `[String : Any]` / `Parameters`) for the said requirement.

[image]

While I did see a similar question to this: [Postman request to Alamofire request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289792/postman-request-to-alamofire-request) but it doesn't have a valid answer. Assume that I'm quite experienced with posting/getting/etc data from various API but I just don't know how to pass raw data just like in the photo above. Please check out my comments too in the code.

Here's what I'm doing with my function for this request:

```
/** Apply to job with Shift.
 *  This service function creates a json data for applying.
 */

func someFuncService(_ job: Job, daySchedules: [(Int, String, Schedule)], withBlock completion: @escaping JobServiceCommonCallBack) {
    AuthService.someFunc { (currentCustomer, accessToken) in
        guard let lalala = currentCustomer?.id,
            let accessT = accessToken else {
                completion(LalaErrors.currentCustomerError)
                return
        }

        guard let jobId = job.id else {
            completion(LalaErrors.modelError)
            return
        }


        let coreService = LalaCoreService()

        let applicantEndpoint = LalaCoreService.Endpoint.Applicant

        let parameters = [
            "param1" : customerId,
            "param2" : jobId,
            "accessToken" : accessToken,
            "shift" : self.generateDataFromDaySchedules(daySchedules) // this returns [String : Any], can be printed into Json using JSON(x)
            ] as Parameters

        GPLog(classSender: self, log: "FINAL PARAMETER: \(parameters)")

        coreService.request = Alamofire.request(
            applicantEndpoint,
            method: .post,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: URLEncoding.default, // I already have tried .httpbody too.
            headers: nil
        )

        coreService.request {
            (response, result) in

            if let error = result?.error {
                if response!.statusCode == 500 {
                    completion(GPKitError.newError(description: "Failed to apply. Please contact the admin."))
                    return
                }

                completion(error)
                return
            }

            // Success
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: So the question is, what I'm doing wrong here? API returns me status code 500 internal server error.

Comment: What is the single header you set up in Postman? You set headers to `nil` in your Alamofire request.

Comment: Header in my Postman is `Content-Type` `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which doesn't matter. Tried removing that in Postman and the request works. All of my requests requires no header.

Comment: I would still give it a try in Alamofire if using that header solves the issue. Set `encoding` to `URLEncoding.httpBody` and use the specified header. Btw is `Parameters` just a typealias for `[String:Any]`?

Comment: It's done now, David. Thank you for your time. See the selected answer. Upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
  coreService.request = Alamofire.request(
        applicantEndpoint,
        method: .post,
        parameters: parameters,
        encoding: URLEncoding.default, // I already have tried .httpbody too.
        headers: nil
    )
```

should be

```
  coreService.request = Alamofire.request(
            applicantEndpoint + accessToken,
            method: .post,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default, 
            headers: nil
        )
```

Comment: Silly me, I've been using that JSONEncoding.default in all of my requests and I didn't even try to use that in this particular request because I thought this won't even work. Thanks!