# How can I create a request in Alamofire body + parameters

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire

I am a novice programmer and I have doubts in my search.
I need to create a request body + parameters, I have found something like 
[Postman Body Raw Request To Swift Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46001798/postman-body-raw-request-to-swift-alamofire)
But I still do not understand where to put the body and where the parameters.
Here is my request:

```
let usersContactInformation: UsersContactInformationBody =  LoginGsonService.init().getUserCreateBody(username: email, password: password, firstName: firstName, secondName: secondName, numberPhone: numberPhone, imei: imei)

    func parametersAccess_token(access_token: String) -> Parameters?  {
            return  ["access_token" : access_token]
        }

            AF.request(MainApi.userCreate,  method: .post, parameters: parametersAccess_token, encoding:
                JSONEncoding.default, headers: HTTPHeadersApi.headersLoginPassword(username: email, password: password)).responseJSON {
                    response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success:
                            do {
                                   print(response)
                            }
                            catch {
                                print(error)
                                self.view.error(message: "\(error)")
                            }
                            break
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print(error)
                            self.view.error(message: "\(error)")
                        }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is demo post request with http header. Actual request depend on your server implementation.

```
let user = "user"
let password = "password"

var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]

if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user, password: password) {
    headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
}
headers[access_token] = access_token
Alamofire.request("\(MainApi.userCreate)/user/password", headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }
```

Comment: I need to create a query with body + parameters + headers.